# Is is possible to keep alert dialog displayed after activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I have a business logic that requires to keep an alert dialog displayed when a transition happens and an activity is destroyed and another one created. 
The activity that is destroyed is the one that starts the alert dialog.
I did some research on my own and did not find any reliable solution.
If you know a solution or some workarounds that could help me that will be great.

Comment: why not you show your alert dialog in second activity(which is visible) ?

Comment: it is required to be displayed on both. because it should be displayed some time on first activity and some time after the second activity is started

Comment: take 1 activity and screens as fragments , show dialog in activity

Comment: Is it implemented now

Answer (score 2):

This is my suggestion for reference only

as allowed,you could run a full transparent Activity first,then set the Dialog to system level，and instantiation Dialgo in your custom application,and you could show and dismiss the Dialog by your application

like this hierarchy ： TransparentActivity(MainLauncher activity) -> Activity1 -> Activity2

you could show Dialog when Activity1 destroy and dismiss it when Activity2 create by your application.

In fact, Dialog is attached to TransparentActivity，so you should override the back button event to prevent returning to TransparentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I usually build my dialog by giving it a reference to the current activity. And that's how at least what the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#DialogFragment) tells us to do. So my quick answer is NO YOU CAN'T.

However an alternative is in place. Instead of creating two different activities, put them in two different fragments. Load them in one single activity where you can hook your dialog. From your activity, you can switch between your two fragments without the need to close your dialog since the activity won't destroy upon fragment switch.

Comment: that was the solution i thought first but the current implementation requires to much refactor in order to change it, but that will probably be the solution

Comment: we all have that one boss who does not understand our pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 protected void showProgressDialog(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setCancelable(false);
    alert.setTitle("your title");
    alert.setMessage(message);
    alert.create().show();

  }

}
```

Extends this `BaseActivity` in your both Activity.
call `showProgressDialog()` method to show your alert message in `FirstActivity` and when `FirstActivity` is `Destroyed` then Call it from `SecondActivity`.